# Redmine's "latest projects" criteria

Tags: projects, redmine

When there are more than 5 projects registered on Redmine, those listed on main page's "Latest projects" box are sorted by creation date descending (more recently created first), leaving old projects (which could have been more often updated) out of the list.

Is there a way to list top 5 projects by activity from highest to lowest, or display all registered projects, in that very box, *without* changing code ? (I don't have access to it).

My version is Redmine 1.0.1.devel (MySQL).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing around the redmine source for 1.0, it looks like there's no setting for sort order:

http://redmine.rubyforge.org/svn/branches/1.0-stable/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb

Comment: OK, so I browsed the `Project` model and `Project.latest` can be called with more than 5 projects, but the controller simply doesn't use that.

Do you know if any of the more recent versions solve this ?

Comment: I'm running 1.1 and it's the same.  I looked at 1.1's Model and it's still hard-coded to sort by created_on DESC.  Sorry.

Comment: You don't even have access to write a plugin?  You could do that and change it from the plugin...

Comment: Good idea! Do you know which column should I aim for project updates ? (so the sort can be based on activity). Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I figured out now that there is a select box in the main page allowing you to jump to ANY project with one click =) All projects are listed! That's what I wanted, to access any project directly from the main page... Thanks for the brainstorming though!

Comment: Oh yeah, that thing's nice :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the code in app/models/project.rb to say something different where it says 'count=5' change it to something like 'count=20':

# returns latest created projects
  # non public projects will be returned only if user is a member of those
  def self.latest(user=nil, count=5)
    find(:all, :limit => count, :conditions => visible_by(user), :order => "created_on DESC")
  end

If you don't have access to the code then you'll have to just keep using the drop down menu instead.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but I think the dropdown is sufficient =)